# Devise customization for registration and confirmation

Tags: java, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I was just about to follow this tutorial:
http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/

But then realized that my Devise needed some customizing. I am very new to Rails, so sorry for anything in advance.

What I am doing:
I need to create a site for a Minecraft server a friend and I are making. I set up devise with no extras, just an access level (admin, moderator, developer, ranks, etc.). I am using mongoid for everything here.

What's the problem? I need to make sure that the user really owns their minecraft account! The way I want to do it: In game you type /register [email], you are sent an email with a confirmation link, you click it and done, you are now registered.

What I am asking: Can someone guide me as to: What I need to do in Java, simply what's needed to be done, not the code (in PHP I've done this before, I opened up a connection to a page, I sent username and a hash as parameters), and what must be done in Rails (Change up some views, totally redo the insides of Devise, just what's needed, and some examples). I'm quite new to rails, so please be nice to my brain! Thanks!

I understand it's a big request for help, but if you have some idea of how this can be done, please help. Thank you for reading!

Edit:
Okay... I really am getting desperate here, I will make it as simple as I can:
How do I customize Devise confirmation? I want it like this: from JAVA I can create a user (with only his username and email) who can't log in because he hasn't confirmed yet. When the site gets this request to make an account, I want to dispatch an email with mailer with a confirmation link. From there, instead of just going ahead and verifying, I need them to type their password and reconfirm it, because remember: the account was created without the password, only username and email! After they fill in the form, their account is active!

Please help, I need this done quickly, my app is quickly growing and it will be a hassle to change this all. Until someone can help me, to make things better in user I am using a method to get what display name I want them to use, right now it's set to email, after someone helps me I can finally make it username!

Thank you for reading, please reply if you know the answer or upvote so someone can provide a good answer!

Comment: I've edited the post to be more concise with my needs, and simpler to understand due to the lack of replies. Please reply quickly! My app is waiting for the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that you already added the username field to the User model created by Devise)

What I would do:

1. Create a simple form, no Devise at all, just a standard form that takes the username and the email.
2. Email the user. This email will have the Devise form and/or a confirmation link.
3. If placing the Devise form in the mail is not possible, have it displayed in the page linked by the confirmation email. Of course, you can now auto-complete all the fields except for the password.

With this approach you don't have to dig in the guts of Devise. Use it out of the box, but until the second interaction with the user.